# Link to new record with automatic belongs_to relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, relationship, belongs-to

In my Rails 3 application I have a simple model relationship which is as follows:

**Animal Model**

```
has_many :claims
```

**Claim Model**

```
belongs_to :animal
has_many :payments
```

**Payments Model**

```
belongs_to :claim
```

The claim table has a column called animal_id and the payments table has a column called claim_id.

I can successfully list all payments owned by a claim.

What I am trying to do is add a link within the animal show view that creates a new claim with the animal_id already set and the same with the claim show view for the new payment link.

From what I have read you can manually create a link_to with the controller and action set, like so:

**Claim Show View**

```
<%= link_to 'Create a Payment', {:controller => "payments", :action => "new", :claim_id => '@claim.id'} %>
```

This doesn't seem to work, although it does correctly link to the new payment page.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Just browsing 'new' view is not the way of creating a record' I guess? What do you do inside your payment controller to handle those variable?

Comment: Currently, nothing. Everything I've read is related to current_user id's. I can't figure out how to pass the claim_id to the payment create form.

Comment: You can use that `:claim_id` to add a hidden input at your payment create form and than you can use that ID inside your payment_controller.

Comment: What's the correct syntax to post the claim_id to the hidden field?

Comment: :) When you send your claim_id as a GET parameter to your payments new view, inside your payments/new.html.erb, you can use it as `params[:claim_id]` . So add that as a value to a hidden field.

Comment: why don't you use nested routes?

Comment: @scaryguy So have a hidden field, or use the controller to add  params[:claim_id] to the claim_id column?

Comment: I think that will make you easier for create. Check here for more info [nested routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the top of my head, and untested, I think the following would work:

```
= link_to 'Create Payment', payments_path(:payment=>{:claim_id=>@claim.id}), :method => :post
```

Adding a hash inside the url helper is just going to put params on the url, which will be interpreted by rails the same way "normal" params posted from a form are.

This will be equivalent to submitting a new payment form, so it will redirect the same way that would. If you want it to be handled via ajax just add `:remote => true`, and be sure your the create action on your PaymentsController responds to javascript correctly.

---

Update: Read your question again, you want the new payment form with the claim_id already set?

Ok, there are many ways you could do this. If you pass params to the new action you can take the claim_id from the params, the same as I showed above for creating a record:

```
= link_to 'New Payment', new_payment_path(:claim_id=>@claim.id)
```

This should link you to /payments/new?claim_id=123

Then in your controller:

```
def new
  @payment = Payment.new(:claim_id => params[:claim_id])
end
```

However, as was pointed out in the comments, the better way to do this is to nest payments under claims:

In your routes:

```
resources :claims do
  resources :payments
end
```

In your PaymentsController:

```
before_filter :load_claim

def new
  @payment = @claim.payments.build
end

def create
  @payment = @claim.payments.build(params[:payment])
  ...
end

private
def load_claim
  @claim = Claim.find(params[:claim_id])
end
```

In your link:

```
= link_to 'New Payment', new_claim_payment_path(@claim)
```

Just be aware that now your payment path helpers will need claims in them, ie:

```
= link_to 'Payment', claim_payment_path(@claim, payment)
```

Same thing for form helpers:

```
= form_for [@claim, @payment] ...
```

Comment: That creates the payment without visiting the form at all, am I missing something?

Comment: Updated answer, your question said "create new payment" not "initialize a new payment" :)

Comment: Ahh thanks, I didn't realise I needed to make changes to the controller after using nested resources in my routes. I'm getting `undefined method `payments_path'` for the form view, should I be altering the form_for section?

Comment: I might have to seperate this into a question because `<%= form_for [@claim, @payment] do |f| %>` results in `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"payments"}`